# Как сделать, что бы поп-ап Vex пропадал через 5с?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет

Такой вопрос: у меня есть поп-ап, который работает на VEX ( github.hubspot.com/vex ) 
Сейчас выводится alert и пропадает по нажатию на ОК. Как сделать, что бы он пропадал или по ОК, или через 5с(5000мс) ?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так:

```
vex.dialog.alert('Hello!')
    .on('vexOpen', function(event, options) {
        // По событию открытия окна устанавливаем таймер
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Проверка нужна на случай, когда пользователь закрыл диалог, нажав кнопку OK,
            // в этом случае $vexContent.data() вернет пустой объект,
            // а $vexContent.data().vex вернет undefined
            if (options.$vexContent.data().vex) {
                vex.close(options.$vexContent.data().vex.id);
            }
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

alert() является предустановленной функцией JavaScript, когда срабатывает alert() - выполнение js-кода останавливается, следовательно, закрыть появившееся модальное окно какой-либо функцией на js нельзя.

Comment: эх, жаль, минус поставить не могу